# Load CSS files in a predetermined order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, load

I am using Ruby on Rails and I would like to ensure that my CSS files are loaded in a predetermined order. The code to accomplish that should be stated in the `application.html.erb` file.

There is some RoR method to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no need for ROR for that. the usual include is okay.

```
<= stylesheet_link_tag "css1", "css2", etc %>
```

or

```
<= stylesheet_link_tag "css1" %>
<= stylesheet_link_tag "css2" %>
<= stylesheet_link_tag "css3" %>
```

Comment: if all else fails - give your css files alphabetical ordered names and stylesheet_link_tag :all !